# Creating subdirectories from another folders subdirectories

Tags: c#

```
string[] oldFilesArray = Directory.GetFiles(oldFolderDialog.SelectedPath, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);            
string[] newFilesArray = Directory.GetFiles(newFolderDialog.SelectedPath, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);         
        foreach (string oldFile in oldFilesArray)
        {
            string oldFileNames = Path.GetFileName(oldFile);
            foreach(string newFile in newFilesArray)
            {
                string newFileNames = Path.GetFileName(newFile);                    
                if (newFileNames == oldFileNames)
                {
                    string extension = ".patch";
                    Environment.CurrentDirectory = Application.StartupPath; //The Application was crashing on Windows XP without this line.
                    ProcessStartInfo bsdiff = new ProcessStartInfo();
                    bsdiff.FileName = "bsdiff.exe";
                    string bspatchArguments = "\"" + Path.GetFullPath(oldFile) + "\"" + " "
                    + "\"" + Path.GetFullPath(newFile) + "\"" + " "
                    + "\"" + updateFolderPathLabel.Text + "\\" + Path.GetFileName(newFileNames) + extension + "\"";                        
                    Process.Start("bsdiff", bspatchArguments);                       
                }                   
            }
        }
```

Hi

I hope the above is posted correctly, I am creating my first project using c#, however I am having some issues, basically what I want to achieve is get the subfolders that a file exists in and then in a new folder create that same subdirectory with the file.

e.g:

folder 1: c:\test\test\test.txt (the path is generated by a user selecting the folder)

folder 2: c:\test1\test\test.txt (same as above)

folder 3: c:\test2 (same as above)

now what I want to happen is in folder 3 a sub directory called test to be created and the file test.txt to be created there.

I tried using Get.Directories but I am getting a full path (c:\test2\c:\test1\text\test.txt) is it possible to only get the \test\test.txt to be created.

There are alot of files and subdirectories and subdirectories within those.

Bsdiff, compares two files and then creates a patch file between them, so I can get it to create patch files for the items that exist in both folders, but I would also like to try get them into the same name folder that they were in previously.

if the code is sloppy :( I am sorry still fairly new to the whole thing.

Thanks

Comment: string newPath = oldPath.Replace(oldRootDirectory, newRootDirectory);